# table cells show first index's data of NSMutableArray in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a NSMutableArray (array2) as data source of table view. I want to add object to that array when i select a cell of searchResultsTableView and reload the self.tableView with that array.

If i add object with array2.addObject() method, then all the cells are okay with individual data.

But, if i add object with array2.insertObject(myObject, atIndex: 0), then all the cells show same data as data of array2[0]. Why ?

My problem is in didSelectRowAtIndexPath function of table view. I always want to add the selected object at the first position of my table view, thats why i implemented with insertObject method instead of addObject method. Below is my code portion.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.array1.count
        }else{
            return self.array2.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            let number = self.array1[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = String(number)
        } else {
            let cell: customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell
            let brand = self.array2[indexPath.row] as NSString
            cell.name.text = brand
            cell.comment.text = "100"
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

            self.array2.insertObject(cell.textLabel!.text!, atIndex: 0)
            //self.array2.addObject(cell.textLabel!.text!)

            self.searchDisplayController!.setActive(false, animated: true)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is weird!... your always returning "let cell = UITableViewCell()" and not in fact your dequeued "cell"

change your method to this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        let number = self.array1[indexPath.row]
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(number)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell: customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell
        let brand = self.array2[indexPath.row] as NSString
        cell.name.text = brand
        cell.comment.text = "100"
        return cell
    }
}
```